# Why would I have to use multiple threads for one processing task if i can turn up the priority of the program?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

Earlier I asked about processing a datastream and someone suggested to put data in a queue and processing this data on a different thead. If this was to slow, I should use multiple threads.

However, i'm using a system that has one core.
So my question is: why not up the prio of my app, so it gets more CPU time from the OS?
I'm writing a server based app and it will be the only big thing running on there.

What would be the pro's and con's of putting the prio up?:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only one core, then the only way that multi-threading can help you is if chunks of that work depends on something other than CPU, so one thread can get some work done while another is waiting for data from a disk or network connection.

If your application has a GUI, then it can benefit from multi-threading in that while it would be no quicker to do the processing (slower in fact, though probably negligibly so if the task is very long), it can still react to user input in the meantime.

If you have two or more cores, then you can also gain in CPU-bound operations though doing so varies from trivial to impossible depending on just what that operation is. This is irrelevant to your case, but worth considering generally if code you write could later be run on a multi-core system.

Upping the priority is probably a bad idea though, especially if you have only one core (one advantage of multi-core systems is that people who up priorities can't do as much damage).

All threads have priorities which is a factor of both their process' priority and their priority within that process. A low-priority thread in a high priority process trumps a high-priority thread in a low-priority process.

The scheduler doles out CPU slices in a round-robin fashion to the highest priority threads that have work to do. If there are CPUs left over (which in your case means if there are zero threads at that priority that need to run), then it doles out slices to the next lowest priority, and so on.

Most of the time, most threads aren't doing much anyway, which can be seen from the fact that most of the time CPU usage on most systems is below the 100% mark (hyperthreading skews this, the internal scheduling within the cores means a hyperthreaded system can be fully saturated and seem to be only running at as little as 70%). Anyway, generally stuff gets done and a thread that suddenly has lots to do will do so at normal priority in pretty much the same time it would at a higher.

However, while the benefit to that busy thread of higher priority is generally little or nothing, the decrement is great. Since it's the only thread that gets any CPU time, all other threads are stuck. All other processes therefore hang for a while. Eventually the scheduler notices that they've all been waiting for around 3seconds, and fixes this by boosting them all to highest priority and giving them larger slices than normal. Now we have a burst of activity as threads that got no time are all suddenly highest-priority threads that all want CPU time. There's a spurt of every thread except the high-priority one running, and the system stops from keeling over, though there's likely still a lot of applications showing "Not Responding" in their title bars. It's far from ideal, but it is an effective way to deal with a thread of higher than usual priority grabbing the core for so long.

The threads gradually drop down in priority, and eventually we're back to the situation where the single higher priority thread is the only one that can work.

For extra fun, if our high priority thread in any way depended upon services provided by the lower priority threads, it would have ended up being stuck waiting on them. Hopefully in a way that made it block and stopped itself from doing any damage, but probably not.

In all, thread priorities are to be approached with great caution, and process priorities even more so. They're only really valid if they'll yield quickly and are either essential to the workings of other threads (e.g. some OS processes will be done at a higher priority, finaliser threads in .NET will be higher than the rest of the process, etc) or if sub-millisecond delays can mess things up (some intensive media work requires this).

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple cores/processors in your system, upping the priority of a single threaded program will not improve your performance by much, because the other cores would still be unused.

The only way to take advantage of multiple processing units is to write your program using multiple threads/processes.

Having said this, setting your multithreaded application to very high priority may lead to some performance improvement, but I really never saw it to be significant, at least in my own tests.

**Edit**: I see now that you are using only one core. Basically your program will be able to run more often on the CPU than the rest of the processes that are of lower priority. This may bring you a marginal improvement, but not a dramatic one. Since we cannot know what other applications are running at the same time on your system, the golden rule here is to try it yourself with various priority levels and see what happens. It's the only valid way to see if things will be faster or not.

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't specify good enough, i was actually talking about a singlecore system, ill edit my message accordingly

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on why the data processing is slow.

If the data processing is slow because it is a genuinely cpu intensive operation then splitting it out into multiple threads on a single core system is not going to get you any benefit. In this case increasing the task priority would provide some benefit, assuming that there is (user) cpu time being used by other processes.

However, if the data processing operation is slow because of some non-cpu restriction (eg. if it is I/O bound, or relying on another process), then:

1. Increasing the task priority is going to have negligible impact. Task priority won't affect I/O times and if there is a dependency on another process on the system you may actually harm performance.
2. Splitting the data processing out into multiple threads can allow the cpu intensive areas to continue processing while waiting for the non-cpu intensive (eg. I/O) areas to complete.

Comment: I think his model is producer-consumer from what I've read, with a single producer handling I/O. I think we can assume the workers are CPU bound.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the priority of a single-threaded process just gives you more (or bigger) time slices on the one core the process is running on.  The core can still only do one thing at a time.

If you spin off a thread to handle the data processing, it can run on a different processor core (assuming a multi-core system), and it and your main thread are actually executing at the same time.  Much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you use only one thread your server app will only be able to service one request at a time, no matter what its priority.  If you use multiple threads you could service many at the same time.

Comment: With that said, there are lots of great single threaded servers out there.